# Adobe Illustrator - prevent U or curly shape strokes filling some space

Tags: adobe-illustrator, brush

I am new in adobe illustrator and basically i'm learning from anything i can find on the internet.

The issue i am having is when I use **calligraphic brush** with width set to **pressure**.

It annoys me a lot when I try to draw a stroke where it curls up and two lines come too close to each other, some space between the lines is getting filled. How can i stop this?

I tried to turn the brush smoothness to as accurate as it goes but nothing changes.. I'm sorry if this is a noob questions, but any ideas?

I tried to draw an example in paint below, to be able to describe my issue. Any suggestion would be appreciated.

Thanks

[image: U-shape stroke, fills the bottom curve automatically]